# how to show country name from web server when i click on Edittext like using drop down box

Tags: android, web-services, spinner

i have a registration page in which i wanted to add country item also

My question is that when i click on edittext box it should show all name of countries list getting from web server and the user can select any country by seeing on list how can i do ??
please provide sample code if any ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: A good tutorial for AutoCompleteText (country, email, map api address) http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-add-autocompletion-to-an-edittext

Answer (score 0):

if you want to response(getting countries name) from web server then it done only through

- api
- WebService

  it gives response in the form of **XML,json etc.**

Comment: ya i have that but my question is that when i click on edittext box than it should show name of the country am using spinner instead of edittext box ?? how can i do this ??

Comment: firstly u should save the list in arraylist or in array then used AutoCompleteTextView instead of edittext or if u use spinner then through spinnerName.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter) u set the country in spinner

Answer (score 0):

For this you want to use AutoCompleteText..

Get the list of all country from the Web Server and store it in String Array or some thing else the see this Demo application for reference [AutoCompleteText](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/AutoComplete1.html)..

Also check [this](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-create-auto-complete-textbox-android)....

Comment: Your server response is JSON or XML?